# How to utilize a DataTemplate with persistent ViewModel(s)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, datacontext, contentcontrol

I started off binding `ContentControls` to Views stored in my `ViewModels`, and while it worked as intended, it broke the `MVVM` pattern I've been trying to follow.  It just felt dirty.  So, based on the recommendation of someone in chat, I learned about `DataTemplates`, implemented it, and it has been an awesome solution.  However, I have run into a snag, most likely the limits of my knowledge, so here I am and thanks in advance.

### Premise

The description of my problem is based on what I've gathered about using `DataTemplates`, so if my premise is wrong, it would be wonderful if you'd hit me up in the comments so I can better my understanding (and for others too if they find this question).

A `ContentControl`'s Content attribute binds to a property in `ViewModel` with a type referring to some interface implemented by any `ViewModel` that may be desired.  **Whenever the property is set to the appropriate `ViewModel`, the `ContentControl` looks at the `DataTemplate` to determine which `View` to load and then it initializes the corresponding View and then that `View` initializes it's own `ViewModel`**.  This last sentence is pretty pivotal so if I'm wrong about that, my understanding is off and **the nature of my problem is not what I think it is**.  Here is a code snippet from a `UserControl` containing a `DataTemplate`:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:ControlCenterVM />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type moduleViewModels:StateVM}">
        <moduleViews:StateView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type moduleViewModels:InputVM}">
        <moduleViews:InputView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type moduleViewModels:TemperatureVM}">
        <moduleViews:TemperatureView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type moduleViewModels:NetworkControlVM}">
        <moduleViews:NetworkControlView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding LeftModule}" />
```

### Problem

The `View` that is loaded creates a new `ViewModel`.  The `ViewModel` I should be using is actually the same exact one that I set to the property bound to the `ContentControl` but it seems to me that it only uses it to do type-matching for the `View` lookup.  Is this correct?

Look at the `DataContext` portion of the code snippet I provided above.  All of my `Views`, **especially the ones that "could" be loaded into the `ContentControl`**, create their `DataContext` like this.  How can I refer to a static `ViewModel` in those areas?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever the property is set to the appropriate ViewModel, the
>   ContentControl looks at the DataTemplate to determine which View to
>   load and then it initializes the corresponding View **and then that View
>   initializes it's own ViewModel**.

You were right about everything except that last part which I've highlighted.

Setting the `Content` property for the `ContentControl` effectively sets the `DataContext` for the view it displays. **This means that you don't have to set the `ViewModel` explicitly from your views.**

Simply remove any modifications you've made to the `DataContext` property in your views and everything should be working as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Works perfectly and the cause and solution are both very clear.